# Obtain scroll position remembered by browser with JavaScript before loading the complete page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know the visible vertical section of a webpage as early as possible while loading the page. Often, this goes from `0` to `$(window).height()`. But if the user has already scrolled, and then reloads the page or comes back to it, many browsers will display the page at the previous scroll position.

Is there a way to determine the scroll position remembered by the browser before the complete page is loaded? $(window).scrollTop() does only work *after* loading the complete page (tested in Firefox20.0).

I would be happy with a solution that works at least in the common and good browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set cookies.Create cookie with variable name of ur choice.Before loading the page set the cookie value.While loading the page take value from the cookie and give it as a parameter to scrooltop function.

Comment: I hoped someone would point me to a trivial solution. But it seems, there is no one. Thanks.